# Prestashop: Mostrar productos en funcion de SQL

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

Necesito mostrar unos productos en concreto a traves de una sql que ya tengo y que funciona bien.

Con JQuery me funciona perfectamente, pero mediante un boton y PHP no se realmente como hacerla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que tengo 2 combos en la pagina de inicio y el usuario debe seleccionar uno y despues otro, para darle al boton de buscar y que muestre dichos prodcutos en funcion de lo elegido en esos dos combos.

No se como deberia plantear ese form y a donde debia llamar ese boton para que me traiga esos productos.

Entiendo que lo hago en el PHP y despues desde el tpl llamo a esa función, pero no se por donde empezar.

¿Alguin me arroja un poco de luz?

Este es el codigo jquery que me funciona:

```
function mostrarproductosporlocalidadyespecialidad(id_localid){
$("#productoselegidos").html("");
var especialidad = $("#sespecialidad").val();
var poblacion = id_localid;
$("#productoselegidos").append("Especialidad: " + especialidad + " Poblacion: " + poblacion);

var params = {
    "especialidad" : especialidad,
    "poblacion" : poblacion
};

$.ajax({
    data: params,
    url: 'adminasesmed/obtenerproductos.php',
    type: 'post',
    /*datatype: 'json',*/
    success: function(response){
        /*Ojo a ese $.parseJSON porque es un bug en jQuery*/
        /*$.each($.parseJSON(response), function(index, data){  
            $("#productoselegidos").append("<br>Id de productos:" + data.id_product);
        });*/
        data = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(data);
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            /*console.log(data[i].id_product);*/
            $("#productoselegidos").append("<div style='float:left'>" + 
                data[i].name + 
                "<br>" + 
                data[i].description_short + 
                "</div>");              
        }           
    }
})
```

}

Gracias

Comment: Lo acano de incluir @lois6b

Comment: entonces tu pregunta seria: como hacer ese codigo en JS con PHP?

Comment: Si. Quiero hacer una funcion en PHP que traiga los productos que necesito en funcion de una SQL que tengo. No se si me explico.

Comment: El caso es que con javascript traigo los productos sin problemas, pero despues al mostrarlos no se como puedo añadir a cada producto la imagen y la opcion de añadir al carro. Así me sería mucho mas facil pero no se como implementarlo. Gracias

Comment: donde haces el `$("#productoselegidos").append(` no puedes añadir la imagen y lo del carro?

Comment: La imagen no se como traerla, porque no veo en que tabla esta la ruta y lo del carrito es que no se como hacerlo :(

Answer (score 0):

No puedo comentarte porque no tengo puntos suficientes aún pero, desde PHP deberías usar el Webservice de Prestashop. No se si lo estás haciendo ahora o si atacas directamente a la base de datos.

Si lo estás haciendo a través del API, la URL a la imagen se encuentra en el campo

```
id_default_image
```

Para obtenerlo tendrías que hacer una petición a

```
/api/products/[Id del producto]
```

Espero servirte de ayuda.